# Why dοes this code output 1?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out this C++ code line by line. 
Can anyone explain it for me? Why is the output 1?

```
int main() {
     int sum = 0;
     for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
           if (sum%2==0)
              sum += i; 
           else
              continue;
     cout << sum << endl;
}
```

Comment: Your code only increments `sum` when it's an even number, therefore the first time `sum` becomes an odd number it will never be incremented ever again.

Comment: Because `sum` is only being set once, the first time through the loop. After that, `sum%2` never equates to `0`.

Comment: You should've used debugger, haven't you?

Comment: im still learning c++.  @NickyC

Comment: @MustafaKhaleel That's why you should've used debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code can be roughly translated to the English:

> Start with a sum of zero then, for every number from 0 to 9 inclusive, add it to the sum if and only if the current sum is even.

So, you'll add zero to the sum (because the sum is currently even) after which the sum will still be zero (hence even).

Then you'll add one to the sum (because the sum is currently even) after which the sum will be one (hence odd).

Then you'll never add anything to the sum again (because it's odd and will remain so because you're not adding anything to it).

*That's* why it outputs one.

---

You may find it more instructive to simply modify your program to output what it's "thinking". The following changes will hopefully make it easier to understand:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << "Processing " << i
             << ", sum is " << sum
             << ((sum % 2 == 0) ? " (even):" : " (odd): ");
        if (sum % 2 == 0) {
            sum += i;
            cout << "adding " << i << " to get " << sum;
        } else {
            cout << "leaving at " << sum;
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
    cout << "Final value is " << sum << '\n';
}
```

Running that code will show you the steps along the way:

```
Processing 0, sum is 0 (even): adding 0 to get 0
Processing 1, sum is 0 (even): adding 1 to get 1
Processing 2, sum is 1 (odd):  leaving at 1
Processing 3, sum is 1 (odd):  leaving at 1
Processing 4, sum is 1 (odd):  leaving at 1
Processing 5, sum is 1 (odd):  leaving at 1
Processing 6, sum is 1 (odd):  leaving at 1
Processing 7, sum is 1 (odd):  leaving at 1
Processing 8, sum is 1 (odd):  leaving at 1
Processing 9, sum is 1 (odd):  leaving at 1
Final value is 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a table trying to simulate the debug steps for you to understand the logic of your code and see why the result is evaluated to 1

[image: debug steps]

Recommendation: learn how to debug. Depending on the IDE you are using they approach code debugging differently. Debug come in handy when you want to understand how your code is being executed.

About your code:

- Try to use curly braces when possible, this helps your code to be clean and more understandable;
- else continue: you don't need this line of code because there's nothing to skip in your loop after else condition;

Answer (score 0):

Exchanging the comparison from

```
if (sum%2==0)
```

to

```
if (i%2==0)
```

would make sense.
This would sum up the even numbers 0+2+4+6+8  -> **20**.